# Hosting a previously played (as client) game

Tags: magicka

Is it possible to host a game (campain) that I played as a client previously?
With all the progress, I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't host the same game, but you can pick a chapter from which to start when hosting. The players' equipment will remain the same if they do not switch robes.

Comment: And the magicks? Some are given to you, but some books can be missed. What about those?

Comment: @Evgeni the magicks you've unlocked in the save slot you're using to host will be available. Note that you don't need to have learned the magicks to cast them.